# How to debug electron applications with IntelliJ or WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea, webstorm, electron

I'm using IntelliJ as development tool and I wanted to know how to debug an [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) application?

I'm aware there is a [standard way](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process.md) to debug Electron applications, but this method is done outside of my IDE.

I've tried to create a new "Node.js" "Run/Debug Configuration" using:

- Node interpreter: `<path to node>`
- Working directory: `<path to my application root folder>`
- JavaScript file: `node_modules/.bin/electron`
- Application parameters: `.`

With this settings, my application starts, but if I put a breakpoint in my `main.js` the application never stops on the breakpoint (= debugging doesn't work).

Answer (score 14):

This is how I set it up, and it worked great. I then just put my break points inside of webstorm and it just works.

In webstorm create a new runtime configuration that looks like this.

[image: Here is a screenshot of my webstorm run configuration]

Comment: I have a similar setup and can run but debugging doesn't work.

Comment: Same as @GrahamWheeler.  Did anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Try to change your node interpreter by the electron executable in your node_modules. It seems to work fine for me ;)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more on this? It seems I cannot make it work (using WebStorm 10). Please list all props so I can test :)

Comment: He means that you add a new run/debug configuration, choose nodejs and change the parameter "node interpreter" to the electron binary. On OSX for example "/usr/local/bin/electron" if you have installed electron via "npm install -g electron-prebuilt" for example. Than you can start and debug the application. My problem at the moment is that the node configuration starts with --debug-brk=[port] witch works with node but not with electron, because electron needs --debug=[port] otherwise it pauses on first line (http://bit.ly/1XHictg). Debug Config sample: https://imgur.com/DqPvLzk

Answer (score 2):

I got debugging to work in the IDE and made some notes for the future
which I'll drop here in case it can help somebody (or even be
improved).

## Debug configuration JetBrains IDE

These instruction are applicable for the code base of
[electron-react-boilerplate on
GitHub](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate)

JetBrains JS debug only works with Chrome or Chromium based web
browsers. I only use Firefox so for this to work, I installed
Chromium for Linux.

#### Enable debug in the project's code

- Add or modifiy **$project_root/.erb/configs/webpack.config.renderer.dev.dll.ts**
  `devtool: 'source-map',`
  `mode: 'development',`
- Add or modify **$project_root/tsconfig.json**
  `"inlineSources": true,`
  `"inlineSourceMap": true,`
- Also worked without this line. Add or modify **$project_root/src/main/main.ts**
  `app.commandLine.appendSwitch('remote-debugging-port', '9229')`

#### JetBrains IDE configuration

To debug in a JetBrains IDE,
first start the application with npm
start run config (screenshot) or terminal,
then run `jsdebug configuration` in JetBrains IDE (screenshot).

When you run the `JavaScript Debug configuration`, a Chromium instance fires up and the debugger should stop in your IDE at breakpoints.

There's definitely room for improvement because I have 2 instances of the GUI  running now, 1 that started with run `npm start` and 1 that started with run  `JavaScript Debug configuration` that allows me to debug in the IDE.

##### Screenshots

[image: npm start configuration]

[image: JavaScript debug configuration]

[image: Add chromium as Browser]

#### Links

[WebStorm debugging JetBrains
docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/starting-the-debugger-session.html#pause-resume)

[JetBrains 2016 debugging
tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/getting-started-with-electron-in-webstorm/)

#### Notes

The Electron app is running on localhost:1212. This information is
not visible in the electron "browser" as there is not address bar,
but it can be discovered in webpack.config.renderer.dev.ts on line
`const port = process.env.PORT || 1212;`.