# Running background tasks in node-webkit (nw)

Tags: node-webkit

I'm trying to run background tasks (file system scanner) using [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/).

In [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/), it can be done using [`child_process.fork`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)`(__dirname + '/path_to_js_file')` and calling `child.on('message', function(param) { ... })` and [`child.send(...)`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle) in the main script and `process.on('message', function(param) { ... })` and `process.send(...)` in the child script.

In NW.js, I tried to use [Web Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) but nothing happens (my webworker script is never executed).

I also saw there is a workaround using [`child_process.fork("path_to_js_file.js", {silent: true, execPath:'/path/to/node'})`](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1575) but that implies bundling Node.js into my future app...

Another idea?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any reasons to use nw.js over electron?

i'm using nw.js at the moment, but wanting to give a shot to electron.

Comment: Yes completly: I couldn't find a good way to debug en electron app... see my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348540/how-to-debug-electron-applications-with-intellij-or-webstorm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what I finally did.

In `package.json` declare a `node-main` property like that:

```json
{
  "main": "index.html",
  "node-main": "main.js"
}
```

Then in your `main.js` use `require('child_process').fork`:

```js
'use strict';

var fork = require('child_process').fork,
    childProcess = fork('childProcess.js');

exports.childProcess = childProcess;
```

In `childProcess.js` communicate using `process.on('message', ...)` and `process.send(...)`:

```js
process.on('message', function (param) {
    childProcessing(param, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.stack);
        } else {
            process.send(result);
        }
    });
});
```

And finaly in `index.html`, use `child_process.on('message', ...)` and `child_process.send(...)`:

```html
    <script>
        var childProcess = process.mainModule.exports.childProcess;
        childProcess.on('message', function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
        childProcess.send('my child param');
    </script>
```

Comment: which nw.js version are you using? i'm using 0.8 ( due to having some sqlite already compiled to win / mac, will try to upload soon ) and all i get is  "Cannot extract package" when trying to use the fork method on my node-main file.

Comment: I'm using the very last one: 0.12.3

Comment: i'll try this now and hope sqlite3 can work on osx and windows targetting that version. ( thanks for your fast replies ).

Comment: Just saw that sqlite3 won't build for nw.js 0.12.3 so i'm locked into 0.8.6 ( and perhaps 0.10 ), i'll have to try this out again soon, need other parts of the app to go ahead at the moment.

Comment: Yes, you just have to use [`nw-gyp`](https://github.com/nwjs/nw-gyp) in order to get it working