# How to debug electron applications with WebStorm that are built in Typescript

Tags: typescript, webstorm, electron

I have followed the instructions here: [How to debug electron applications with IntelliJ or WebStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348540/how-to-debug-electron-applications-with-intellij-or-webstorm)

which has an answer that works well with code written in JS.  All our electron code is written in Typescript that is eventually transpiled through webpack.

However, if I specify in the configuration to use my main.ts entry point, Electron shows the error below.  What do I need to do to get this workflow going?

[image]

Comment: you need passing your compiled entry point to electron (main.js or whatever it's called), electron can't run typescript natively

Comment: Yup, I know that much, the question is about how to setup a flow to make this all work together nicely.

Comment: well, the setup depends on your configuration/code you'd like to debug. Would you like to debug main process or render process? The latter doesn't currently work, btw - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20976

Comment: Just the main process.  Currently we have webpack running in watch mode. Would be nice to change the code, restart the debugging process and have it work with sourcemaps.

Comment: works fine for me when using Typescript + electron + Node.js run configuration... Haven't ever tried this with main process built with webpack (it can be different because of a special way webpack sourcemaps are created). Test project would be helpful

Comment: see http://richb-hanover.com/debugging-webpack-apps-with-webstorm-2016-1/, https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/09/debugging-webpack-applications-in-webstorm/ for some hints

Comment: Thanks Lena.  We have it working now.  But I can't give you an answer. :)